# RegEx: How can I match optional comma separated integers between 5 to 100?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a comma separated string that can be empty. The following strings would pass:

1. `""`
2. `"12"`
3. `"5,100"`
4. `"5,34,55,12"`
5. `"5,8,15,9,94"`

The following would fail:

1. `"2"` - Because 2 is less than 5
2. `"4,15"` - Because 4 is less than 5
3. `"87, 3"` - Because 3 is less than 5
4. `"39,7,23,62, 1"` - Because 1 is less than 5
5. `"25,"` - Because no number comes after the comma

Currently I have the the following regex: `^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$` which is able to match comma separated integers. What I'm not able to do is matching that all the integers are between 5 and 100.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly are you trying to do? What's the string you have against which you need to run a regex match? Can you clearly format your question to include what you've tried so far, what's the sample input and what's the expected output?

Comment: Without capturing groups [`^(?:(?:100|[1-9][0-9]|[5-9])(?:,(?:100|[1-9][0-9]|[5-9]))*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Oljb0f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex: `^((?:[5-9]|([1-9][0-9])|100)(,(?:[5-9]|([1-9][0-9])|100))*)?$` should check numbers between 5 - 100.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HAgoPv/1)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using this regex:

`^(([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)(,([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100))*)?$`

Breakdown:

`^` marks the start.

`$` marks the end of the string.

`?` makes the string optional i.e. one or zero occurrences of the string.

`([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)` matches numbers `5 - 9` or `10 to 99` or `100` respectively.

`(,([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100))*` means that there can be zero or more occurrences of a comma followed by a number between 5 - 100.

Answer (score 0):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/I5jtcW/1) `^(?!.*(?:\b[1-4]\b|^\s*,|,\s*,|,\s*$)).*$` must exclude strings containing numbers 1, 2, 3, or 4.